# Dash Client Side Error Handling on Callbacks

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, plotly

Some of our Dash callbacks involve calling an external API which is authorized through OAuth (Authlib is being used).  When a user signs out their OAuth token is removed from their current session. However, if that user has another tab open, the (ReactJS) AJAX callbacks can continue to be called from that tab but will ultimately fail as there is no longer a valid token.

Ideally what would happen is if the user is no longer authorized during a callback a 401 response will be returned and that would somehow trigger the browser to redirect to the Flask application root (which will now detect they need to login and redirect to the OAuth server for login)

In my callbacks I can include something similar to:

```
@dashapp.callback(
    Output('some-div', 'children'),
    Input('some-input', 'data')
    )
def my_fancy_callback(inputdata):
    if not session.get('token'):
      raise SessionExpiredException
    jsonResult = api.get('https://myapi.com/someinterestingdata')
    return jsonResult
```

And then have a Flask error handler that catches this specific exception and returns a 401 response:

```
@app.errorhandler(SessionExpiredException)
def handle_SessionExpired_exception(e):
    return Response("Access Denied", 401)
```

This indeed results in the AJAX call returning a 401 response (as seen on the browser network output).  However, I'm not sure how I can hook into this call on the React/Browser side of things?  With Dash I could look at adding some custom JavaScript files to maybe somehow intercept XMLHttpRequest globally but I was wondering if there was already built in support with Dash to accomplish this?

I am very new to Python/Flask/Dash/Plotly so if there is another best practice for client side error handling I would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting Dash apps on Flask behind OAuth is possible without the Dash Enterprise middleware but it's not intuitive to get it set up.  I use an application factory method with the following components to protect dash applications.

This pattern will check auth status on all Dash layouts and callbacks without any specific callback code.

```
my_dash_app = Dash(
    __name__,
    server=flask_server,
    url_base_pathname=f'/{base_pathname}/',
    assets_folder=assets_folder,
    meta_tags=[meta_viewport],
    external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets,
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
    external_scripts=external_scripts
)
protect_dash_views(my_dash_app)
```

```
def protect_dash_views(my_dash_app):
    for view_func in my_dash_app.server.view_functions:
        if view_func.startswith(my_dash_app.config.url_base_pathname):
            my_dash_app.server.view_functions[view_func] = azure_authentication_required(
                my_dash_app.server.view_functions[view_func])
```

```
def azure_authentication_required(protected_function):
    @wraps(protected_function)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):

        if not user_is_employee():  # flask session cookie has expired, force user to login again.
            return redirect(url_for("login"))

        if user_is_blocked_from_access():
            return abort(403, 'You do not have permission to access This Application.')  # prevents further code execution.

        if azure_access_token_is_expired():
            user_id = get_azure_user_id()
            get_refresh_token_from_cache(user_id=user_id)  # this routine aborts code 403 if not successful.

        return protected_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_function
```

Comment: This is similar to what we are doing now and it does / can indeed protect Flask routes and perhaps callbacks.  However, if the user has already loaded the dash app (React) and then at some point their session expires a callback results in a 401.  In that case, it doesn't seem clear how one can deal with this on the React side (client browser).  I believe a redirect will only cause the AJAX call to maybe redirect but that won't actually redirect the main react app.  I guess this issue could also be phrased "how to deal with client side React errors when using Dash"